# Check process of a single SSH tunnel in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

On a remote lab system, I have a shell script that initiates a reverse SSH tunnel to my main jumpbox that gets run with a cron job every 5 minutes.  If the SSH tunnel is up nothing happens, if it is down it initiates it.

```
#!/bin/bash
createTunnel() {
/usr/bin/ssh -N -R :2222:localhost:22 username@jumpbox.example.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
 echo Tunnel to jumpbox created successfully
else
 echo An error occurred creating a tunnel to jumpbox. RC was $?
fi
}
/bin/pidof ssh
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo Creating new tunnel connection
  createTunnel
fi
```

This has been extremely reliable to ensure my access to the remote machine if it gets rebooted or as my jumpbox IP changes.
However, I recently added a second SSH tunnel to this system and had a situation where one of the two tunnels went down and was never re-established.  It appears that since there was one tunnel up, the pidof output still returned with a PID so the script never ran "createTunnel".
Since I have two SSH tunnels, the pidof output shows both PID's:

```
$ /bin/pidof ssh
28281 28247
```

How can I adjust my script to determine if only one of the tunnels is down?

Comment: You may be reinventing the wheel, which in your case is `autossh -f ...` that never exits. It's not clear whether the two connections are to the same endpoint `username@jumpbox.example.com`. If so, a single `ssh` (or `autossh`) can create both tunnels, just use additional `-R` or `-L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts:

1. Pid files. I think this is a general approach.
2. [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), use `autossh`.

(Some other answers may elaborate these ideas.)

3. There are two scripts, right? (not exactly complying with [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)). Give them different names. Your script waits for its `ssh` to exit. The additional instance, instead of checking pid(s) of `ssh`, should check pid(s) of its own name. Exactly <s>one pid</s> two pids mean no previous script is still running:

   ```
   [ $(pidof -x scriptname | wc -w) -eq 2 ] && createTunnel
   ```

   Why two? Because `$()` starts a subshell that also counts. Quite dirty, oh well.
4. Somewhat outside-the-box, I think. Create two symlinks with unique names, like:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/ssh ssh-foo
   ln -s /usr/bin/ssh ssh-bar
   ```

   Let the first script run `ssh-foo`, let the second run `ssh-bar`. Their `pidof` invocations should target `ssh-foo` or `ssh-bar` respectively as well. This way they won't mix. As a bonus, additional `ssh` (possibly run for a completely different reason in the future) won't affect them.

**And finally:**

5. **You don't have to check anything.**

   ```
   /usr/bin/ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N -R :2222:localhost:22 username@jumpbox.example.com
   ```

   If the tunnel already exists, port forwarding will fail for sure and `ssh` will exit. I guess you can run this line directly from a crontab, no script is required.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  Using "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes" in the command I am initiating the SSH tunnels from by crontab directly.  The only thing I added was ">> /dev/null 2>&1" to prevent the user mailbox from being filled up with the cron failures.    `/usr/bin/ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N -R :2222:localhost:22 username@jumpbox.example.com >> /dev/null 2>&1`