# SSH tunnel created from remote location but unreliable access from local computer

Tags: ssh-tunnel

Two computers:

1. Desktop-Ubuntu; fixed local IP, connected to a modem with port 22 open and forwarding to it.
   Because of dynamic IP I have a no-ip account. So domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com forwards incoming requests to this computer.
2. Remote Raspberry Pi 3 connected to a cellular network that has all incoming requests closed by ISP.

I need SSH access from Desktop-Ubuntu to RPi. Because it is not possible directly I built a tunnel. After all sort or tries to get it work persistently (`autossh` e.g.), this is my schema:

**At RPi**:

`sshd_config`:

```
 ClientAliveInterval 120     
 ClientAliveCountMax 720
```

Crontab each 5 minutes to check if `ssh` process ID is not null.
`screen` is used to keep `ssh` output is a separate shell window.

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /path-to/check-ssh-tunnel.sh
```

`check-ssh-tunnel.sh`:

```
COMMAND="/usr/bin/screen -dmS ssh-Ubuntu /usr/bin/ssh -R 2255:localhost:22 user@domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com -g"
COMMAND_SSH="/usr/bin/ssh -R 2255:localhost:22 domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com -g"
PID=$(/usr/bin/pgrep -f -x "$COMMAND_SSH")
if [ "$PID" = "" ]
then
    $COMMAND
fi
```

Here's the related `ps aux | grep ssh` I get 3 hours after reboot:

```
pi        2128  0.0  0.2   5396  2252 ?        Ss     08:25     0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS ssh-Desktop-Ubuntu /usr/bin/ssh -R 2255:localhost:22 user@domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com -g  
pi        2130  0.0  0.5   9132  4748 pts/0    Ss+  **08:25**   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -R 2255:localhost:22 user@domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com -g
```

If I `kill 2128` cron works and:

```
pi        4755  0.0  0.2   5396  2092 ?        Ss     11:25     0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS ssh-Desktop-Ubuntu /usr/bin/ssh -R 2255:localhost:22 user@domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com -g     
pi        4756  0.0  0.5   9132  4840 pts/0    Ss+  **11:25**   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -R 2255:localhost:22 user@domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com -g
```

To access RPi **from Desktop-Ubuntu**:

```
ssh -p 2255 pi@localhost
```

My problem is that this connection acts random:

- sometimes it ask for a password and I get connected
- sometimes `ssh: connect to host localhost port 2255: Connection refused`
- sometimes it takes a long time to finally output `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`
  After retry: `Connection refused`.

**Back to RPi** nothing seems to be changed:

```
$ screen -r      # to get the ssh window
user@domain-Desktop-Ubuntu.com~$ ssh -p 2255 pi@localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2255: Connection refused
```

At this time and for all those tests I am managing RPi remotely using Teamviewer.
For some reasons I don't want to use it in the future unless it would be absolutely necessary.
That's why I need a SSH tunnel.

What is wrong? How to make the tunnel work reliably?

Comment: `ClientAliveInterval` etc. matters on the server. Your RPi is a client when it tries to establish the tunnel. The values are very high for this purpose, I think. Check [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1283597/432690). The connection that tries to establish the tunnel should fail if port forwarding didn't succeed. Check [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1281720/432690) and use `ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`. If my two links helped, please upvote my answer(s) there and write your own here (with links maybe). If they didn't help, give some feedback.

Comment: On the client side you may want to use `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` (these are for `ssh`, not for `sshd`).

Comment: Did my links help? If so, are you going to write an answer? or should I?

Comment: Yes, great! I already upvoted both linked answers and your previous comments some days ago. `ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` was the key