# KiTTY (fork of PuTTY) script that kills a specific PID automatically

Tags: linux, ssh, script, putty, kitty

## **New version**

So, I'll make a list of the things that I have in order to be clearer.

- PC on windows 10 running a Plex media server and Kitty
- VPS by OVH running on Debian 9 stretch

what I want :

- want to access my server from anywhere out of the local network

how :

- by using the vps as a tunnel to my Plex server

Problem :

- dynamic ip Double Nat from isp side 4G / LTE router with a subscription
- no port forwarding possible

issue :

- when ip change "daily" on the PC (windows 10) the connection to the vps through kitty would crash

manual solution to the issue :

- find the PID of the process that hold the port open and kill it

what I need :

- to make that automatically or have another solution to the issue

## **Pictures to help you understand**

[After ip change in the log of Kitty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOlUY.png)

[Manual way of resolving the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5AQE.png)

## Q&A

***Pimp Juice IT*** : thanks ^^ anyhow the no-ip tool also seemed to me quite fitted. But since the isp has double NAT and that basically i would have to run one No-ip soft on their second "router" behind mine. Which is impossible you would agree ^^. Really like my issue is really simple, indeed but annoying because it seems like the way out of this is simple. But can't get the right way :/

ps : yeah don't worry the old version is a big draft of what i wanted it to be ^^ in the new one you have all taht you need to help me i guess :/ ^^

## ***`Old version`***

> I have a VPS from OVH which I use to tunnel my media server on PLEX
>   from my PC to the VPS. All good and working, except…
>
> My IP is dynamic and double NAT-ed. My external IP changes and renews
>   often, at least once a day. Therefore my connection to the VPS through
>   Kitty (a fork of PuTTY) breaks. That I solved with automated
>   reconnection after a connection abort. Anyhow when that is done the
>   port tunneling that I specified in KiTTY would fail, why because the
>   previous connection wasn’t properly closed.
>
> For the server side it's Debian 9 Stretch.
>
> I found the solution which is that I find the PID of the very
>   connection and kill it *manually*. There is my issue, I would like to
>   automate that with a script. Here I call for your help by hoping
>   anybody could be giving a hand.
>
> Ps: my skills in scripting are as low as it could seem so be as clear
>   as possible thanks.
>
> ---
>
> #### Answers to some comments
>
> ***Scott*** – when my IP address changes it would crash the connection. Right then it would reconnect thanks to KiTTY. I would in
>   the command line just type in `netstat -lnp`, it would show me all the
>   connection alive. I would find the one linked with the specified port
>   (in this case `32400`) and the PID that's associated, then kill the
>   very `PID` with `kill`. Last time the PID was `12007` for example.
>
> ***Kamil Maciorowski*** – I tried this (referring to [this answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/1283733/432690)):
>
> > permanently by editing the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, add:
> >
> > ```
> > net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300
> > ```
>
> and
>
> > If only you can reconfigure `sshd` on the server, this is in my opinion
> >     the most elegant way. Let the `sshd_config` contain lines like:
> >
> > ```
> > ClientAliveCountMax 3
> > ClientAliveInterval 15
> > ```
>
> but neither of those work for me when I simulated a crash of my
>   connection it will reconnect and the port would still be occupied.
>
> Also the solution under
>
> > Back to the client
>
> would seem like working for me only if I would be able to make it fit
>   to my situation.
>
> > "but neither of those work for me when I simulated a crash of my
> >     connection it will reconnect and the port would still be occupied" –
> >     Did you restart sshd? Did you attempt to reconnect right away? With
> >     these settings you need to wait up to one minute for the port becoming
> >     free. – Kamil Maciorowski
>
> yes, I did restart the SSHD with the following command :
>
> > /etc/init.d/ssh restart
>
> and to be safe because I don't know it that restart sshd
>
> > service sshd restart
>
> the reconnection is automated and instant I'm now looking for a way to
>   delay this process if you know how just tell me thanks so you know the
>   :
>
> > ```
> > net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300
> > ```
>
> I set to 10 sec rather than 300 is that still alright.
>
> Also I didn't quite get your second comment about loading two sessions
>   at once fixing it with the second one my goal is to just restart the
>   actual session process which is automated just now need the port to be
>   set free so I can re open it with the new bond.
>
> > Clarification: in my comment above there is a generic way to prevent
> >     locking oneself out of server. If you broke sshd_config severely
> >     enough, you wouldn't be able to ssh anew. That's why you should always
> >     test it with a new connection, while the old one still allows you to
> >     revert changes no matter what. Note in general it's possible to have a
> >     syntactically valid sshd_config and still not be able to connect; so
> >     restarting sshd without any error doesn't necessarily mean it's going
> >     to work. – Kamil Maciorowski
>
> So in the end like what are my solutions for this process to be
>   automated and the port to be freed after a shorter period of time and
>   how to delay the reconnection in kitty with a script or something else
>   ? again thanks man for you time I appreciate
>
> > "the reconnection is automated and instant I'm now looking for a way
> >     to delay this process" – you mean KiTTY tries to reconnect without any
> >     delay, right? In Linux on the client side your problem can easily be
> >     solved by autossh or looping ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes … (see
> >     this answer). I think ssh under Cygwin should support this option. If
> >     you insist on a server-side script, I guess it can be done; but the
> >     script must not kill the tunnel if it's not the old tunnel. I have no
> >     time now to provide such a cumbersome solution; maybe in 12 hours. –
> >     Kamil Maciorowski
>
> Okay thanks I'll see you in 12h anyway until then I'll try all the
>   other solution I'll let you know how it goes thanks again man.

Comment: It would help if you would describe the exact procedure you use for manually finding the PID of the connection.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You tagged "[tag:windows]". I assume it refers to both client and server side. Solution for Linux `sshd` server is in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1283733/432690), server-side story, `ClientAliveCountMax` and `ClientAliveInterval`.

Comment: "but neither of those work for me when I simulated a crash of my connection it will reconnect and the port would still be occupied" – Did you restart `sshd`? Did you attempt to reconnect right away? With these settings you need to wait up to one minute for the port becoming free.

Comment: Note on restarting `sshd`: [*Does restarting sshd always keep existing sessions alive?*](https://superuser.com/q/60407/432690) To be extra safe keep your original session alive and connect another session after you apply the changes. If you cannot connect, which means you would lock yourself out, then use the first session to fix it.

Comment: Clarification: in my comment above there is a generic way to prevent locking oneself out of server. If you broke `sshd_config` severely enough, you *wouldn't* be able to ssh anew. That's why you should always test it with a new connection, while the old one still allows you to revert changes no matter what. Note in general it's possible to have a syntactically valid `sshd_config` and still not be able to connect; so restarting `sshd` without any error doesn't necessarily mean it's going to work.

Comment: "the reconnection is automated and instant I'm now looking for a way to delay this process" – you mean KiTTY tries to reconnect without any delay, right? In Linux on the client side your problem can easily be solved by `autossh` or looping `ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes …` (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1281741/432690)). I think `ssh` under Cygwin should support this option. If you insist on a server-side script, I guess it can be done; but the script must not kill the tunnel if it's not the old tunnel. I have no time now to provide such a cumbersome solution; maybe in 12 hours.

Comment: (1) The rule is: one problem, one question. Your last edit introduces a completely new issue, it should be a separate question. (2) Without any changes it would be a terrible question. [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/355310)? You should specify what you are trying to reach via what tunnel. E.g. a HTTP server may host multiple sites on a single IP address, single port. What site you'll get depends on URL you use. Unrecognized URL will be rejected. (3) Please build all your sentences with punctuation. I'm tired of splitting these streams of words you use into valid sentences.

Comment: That thread of comments is "*unique*"!!! Lions, and tigers, and unique comment threads in answers; oh my!!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, I'm glad to see you getting so much practice in editing questions and I can certainly appreciate that effort so go @argaudbastien, it's your birthday!! Seriously though, without overthinking it, does it sound like something such as https://www.noip.com/login and using [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) could be a workable solution to the changing ISP public IP address issue... https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/

Comment: I was not interested in reading the Old Version since it's old to me that rings "irrelevant" and thus no need to dig into it.